# How to get the story of reopened task in asana with the webhook notification?

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am getting notified via webhooks when the task is reopened by the user,
Where in webhooks i receive a json payload as,

[{"resource":11111111111,"action":"added","parent":2222222222,"created_at":"2016-09-26T06:06:09.283Z","type":"story","user":33333333333}]

Thus to get the story of the reopened task , I use the resource-id to get the taskstory (getTaskStories Api).

Where am getting the changes for all other actions made like creating task,deleting task,completing task,commenting task with the same resource-id which i get from the json-payload.

But i dont get the story of the reopened task.
Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Can you please tell us more about the issue that you are having? Can you post an example `curl -v` request that you are using to view the event (with authentication credentials redacted)? Otherwise, what client library are you using, and can you post an example request using that client library, and the response you get?

One possible explanation is that, if a task is completed and quickly reopened, then the completion and reopening stories cancel each other out, and neither is displayed. Is this plausible in your use case?

Comment: Hi Sean,
Thanks for getting to me , Its working fine. What you said is correct, Am reopening the task as soon as it gets completed. Thus the both are cancelling each other. Thank You for the immediate reply.